# I can't unlock Captain Falcon!

Tags: super-smash-bros

On the original Super Smash Bros for N64, I read in many, many places that to unlock Captain Falcon you need to beat the single player game in under 20 minutes on any difficulty. Well, according to my watch, I beat it in 16 minutes, including the credits, without losing a single life. I expected to play against Captain Falcon, but he did not show up, and is not in my character roster.

Are there more requirements to unlock him? Do I need to try again? Is my cartridge glitched?

Comment: it should just be beat single player in under 20 minutes. try again?

Comment: Did another hidden character appear instead? Only one shows up.  I remember Jigglypuff blocking me from another one.

Comment: @mmathews no, I had jiggly and Luigi airway

Comment: *already. Autocorrect

Comment: A better title might be "How do I unlock Captain Falcon"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I unlock all the characters/stages in Super Smash Bros. 64?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310015/how-do-i-unlock-all-the-characters-stages-in-super-smash-bros-64)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro It's not a duplicate, as *I've already tried what is told to be done* in order to unlock the character. I know how to, but I am having issues with one aspect of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Wikia page](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Captain_Falcon_(SSB)#How_to_unlock), the unlock requirements are as follows:

> Complete 1P Game in under 20 minutes and with no continues, then defeat Captain Falcon on Planet Zebes.

However, it sounds like you should have accomplished this. My only suggestion would be to try again and see if the same thing happens.

Comment: I tried again, beat the game in just under 11 minutes, and he showed up. I'm still concerned as to WHY he didn't in the first place though...

Answer (score 1):

I do believe you have to get all the way to the screen where a new fighter "approaches" in under 20 minutes. I don't think you need a higher difficulty. On the bonus stages, kill yourself quick, and try to end normal stages with a quick knockoff and juggle them down to try and get that fast time!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try not speeding up the credits. It might include the full time of credits. And maybe you have to beat the bonus rounds as well. I have the exact same problem, but I just beat it in 19 minutes. Maybe it is until the character's picture shows up.